Call an async function in Pydantic custom Validator
I have 2 Paydantic models Article and Author defined as follow:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Author(BaseModel):
    id: int
    first_name: str


class Article(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    authors: List[Author]

These models are used to parse and validate python dict that looks like:
article_data = {"id": 568, "name": "Smart People", "authors": [{"id": 123}, {"id": 456}]}

to get get authors details I have an async function that from an id, it returns autho details:
async def get_author(id: int) -> Optional[dict]:
    # Simulate fetching author details from a database or other source
    authors = {
        123: {"id": 123, "first_name": "George Bob"},
        456: {"id": 456, "first_name": "Alice Smith"},
    }
    return authors.get(id) 

to fill author detail in the article object I implemented a custom validator, so the definition of Article class:
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Article(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    authors: List[Author]

    @validator("authors", pre=True)
    def populate_author(cls, value):
        return [Author(**(get_author(item.get("id")))) for item in value]

to run the code, I am using this code snippet:
async def main():
    article = Article.parse_obj(article_data)
    print(article)


asyncio.run(main())

this would not work as I am not awaiting get_author.
when changing my code to use await get_author it will raise:
SyntaxError: asynchronous comprehension outside of an asynchronous function

which is expected as populate_author is not async function trying to await a async funtion get_author
Another alternative I tried is to make the validator async: async def populate_author(cls, value): this will raise this error:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'populate_author' was never awaited

which is expected as well knowing how Pydantic is implemented.
In this case, what is the solution to run an async function inside a custom Pydantic validator?
Pydatic version 1.10.14 with python 3.11


Pydantic validation must be CPU bound, not I/O bound operation. So, I think you have to modify your data as per your database outside pydantic validators. Pydantic maintainer comment related: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/857#issuecomment-537570546

This might sound annoying, but actually it provides a clear divide between pure data validation and checking the data is valid as per your database etc.
So, I also think validation of pure data and validation as per your database, e.g, should be divided.


If you really want to implement async function call from sync function, you can use event_loop functions, such as run_until_complete, etc.
Related answers here: Call async function from sync function, while the synchronous function continues : Python

